# Bold or italicize section of text in MS Access report text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there anyway to make a section of text in a report text box stand out? It can be bold, italicized, underlined, highlighted.. Anything to make it stand out more than the rest of the text in the same text box.

The text to be manipulated would be enclosed with *** on both sides.

I am on MS Access for Office 365 - 16.0.10730.20264 32bit

Comment: If it's all in the same text box is there a property called TextFormat that you can change to RichText?

Comment: Yes, there is. Thanks - but when I try to change it I get a message box stating "the setting you entered isn't valid for this property".

Comment: Alright I have been able to set it as a rich text box by changing the record source query.

Comment: Ah, okay ya I am using a blank text box without a source or any binding. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be the de-facto way to do this but, this is what I have done in the past. Access uses html in the background of a rich text box. I'll post an answer with some screenshots that should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The code behind that button is here.

```
Private Sub Command20_Click()
    Me.Text18.Value = Me.Text15.Value
End Sub
```

The Text15 is the Rich Text Box and the Text18 is plain text. When you go to set the value of the rich text box in code (Text15 in this example) you'll need to write out exactly to what you see in the right depending on what you need.

Comment: Awesome. So my SQL query is returning the text from a table to the form, and the text box is bound to a field returned. the text will look like "Proceed to step 2 ***with caution***" and I only want to make the "with caution" impacted by the rich text format.

Comment: If they have to write back to the field it's going to be a little wild but, you got a couple options. You could put the html in the database table field and report immediately. OR you could send it to a plain text box that has visible set to false. Then take the hidden textbox value on change event to make modifications for the rich text box to make it look like this <div>Proceed to step 2 <em><strong>with caution</strong></em></div> then set that to the rich text box the user sees. Honestly though I would just have it in the database field itself. A lot less code and junk on your form.

Comment: Keep in mind that html can sometimes get pretty long and the database field will have a limit to the string length when you try to store it there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look to store it in the db.